# Execute code after fs.writeFile using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function, `startSurvey`, which, when run, checks if there are questions in a .json file. If there are no questions, it fetches some questions from Typeform and writes them to the .json file using `saveForm`. After it writes, I would like to continue executing some code that reads the .json file and logs its contents. Right now, `await saveForm()` never resolves.

I have promisified the fs.readFile and fs.writeFile functions.

```js
//typeform-getter.js

const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const fetch = require('cross-fetch')
require('dotenv').config()

const conf = require('../../private/conf.json')
const typeformToken = conf.tokens.typeform

const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

const getForm = async () => {
  const form = await fetch(`https://api.typeform.com/forms/${process.env.FORM_ID}`, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `bearer ${typeformToken}`
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  const fields = form.fields
  return fields
}

const saveForm = async () => {
  const form = await getForm()
  return writeFile(__dirname + '/../data/questions.json', JSON.stringify(form))
    .then((e) => {
      if (e) console.error(e)
      else console.log('questions saved')
      return
    })
}


module.exports = saveForm
```

```js
//controller.js

const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const request = require('request')
require('dotenv').config()

const typeformGetter = require('./functions/typeform-getter')

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const saveForm = util.promisify(typeformGetter)

let counter = 1
const data = []

const getQuestions = async() => {
  console.log('called')
  try {
    let data = await readFile(__dirname + '/data/questions.json')
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    return data
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error getting questions from read file', e)
  }
}

const startSurvey = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const questions = await getQuestions()
    if (!questions) await saveForm()
    console.log(questions) //NEVER LOGS
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error: ', error)
  }
}

startSurvey() //function called
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with your code, but, is `console.error('error: ', error)` executed?

Comment: No, that does not get executed....

Comment: Put a `console.log` after `await getQuestions` and let me know if it is called.

Comment: "*`.then((e) => {
      if (e) console.error(e)`*" is not how you handle errors with promises

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande the console.log after await getQuesions() is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your exact error, but there are multiple things wrong with your code:

You're using incorrectly the promisified version of `fs.writeFile`, if an error occurs, **the promise will be rejected**, you won't get a resolved promise with an error as the resolved value, which is what you're doing.
Use `path.join` instead of concatenating paths.

In `startSurvey`, you're using `console.log(questions)` but that wont have any data if `questions.json` doesn't exists, which should happen the first time you run the program, since it's filled by `saveForm`, so you probably want to return the questions in `saveForm`

So `saveForm` should look something like this:

```
const saveForm = async () => {
    const form = await getForm();
    const filePath = path.join(path.__dirname, '..', 'data', 'questions.json');
    await writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(form));

    console.log('questions saved');

    return form;          
 }
```

And `startSurvey`

```
const startSurvey = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const questions = await getQuestions() || await saveForm();
    // This will be logged, unless saveForm rejects
    // In your code getQuestions always resolves
    console.log(questions); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error: ', error)
  }
}
```

In your **controller.js** you're using `util.promisify` on `saveForm` when it is already a promise.

So it should be:

```
const saveForm = require('./functions/typeform-getter')
```

Comment: Saw a missing fs. for writeFile